# Rotate object without coroutine?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a Time of Day system, and in that system I want to be able to control at which hour SUNRISE starts, DAY start, SUNSET starts and NIGHT starts. At the moment this is possible in the system and when the "clock" hits the next start hour I start a Coroutine to start the rotating of the sun and moon.

My coroutine looks like this:

```
IEnumerator RotateSun(Vector3 fDegrees, float SecondsDuringTimeSet)
{
    Quaternion quaFromPosition = _lSunLight.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion quaToPostion = Quaternion.Euler(fDegrees);

    for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / SecondsDuringTimeSet)
    {
        _lSunLight.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(quaFromPosition, quaToPostion, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

And as you see I pass values into that for each time I run it. This is done like this:

```
    if (_fCurrGameHour == _fTimeStartSunrise && _bMoveSunAndMoonOnlyOnce == true)
    {
        // Which TIMESET should it be:
        _en_CurrTimeSet = TimeSet.SUNRISE;

        // How long should the SUN move and how many which degree should it reach before that time ends
        vec3MoveSun = new Vector3(10.0f, 0, 0);
        StartCoroutine(RotateSun(vec3MoveSun, _fConvertSunriseToGTSeconds));

        // How long should the MOON move and how many which degree should it reach before that time ends
        vec3MoveMoon = new Vector3(180.0f, 0, 0);
        StartCoroutine(RotateMoon(vec3MoveMoon, _fConvertSunriseToGTSeconds));

        // Tell bool that we don't need to move the sun and moon more then once
        _bMoveSunAndMoonOnlyOnce = false;
    }
```

And as I wrote this system works at the moment. However it is kind of a static system. So at the moment I need to make sure that the starting hour of the game is the sunrise hour. Otherwise my coroutine would break since it would not rotate to the correct position before the day start hour. And I can definitly not start the game close to sunset then the sun rotates the complete wrong way since it's closer to rotate the wrong way then (I assume).

So my first question is: Could I somehow make the system more dynamic? I want to be able to still set at which hours SUNRISE, DAY, SUNSET and NIGHT should start so during different season for example I could have different lengths on my day. I want to be able to change these hours in the game and then if the SUNSET would be set later the sun would start to rotate a little slower since it is supposed to take longer to reach it's SUNSET position.

Onto my second question: Would it also be possible to rewrite my coroutine so I could start the game at any hour I want and the sun would still start at the right degree rotation?

The sun will always set at the same rotation (170 degrees) and rise at the same rotation (350 degree). I just want to control the time it takes before it reaches to those rotations. Maybe I could somehow move this to my update phase instead of using a Coroutine for this? I have no clue how to change this in my system so if anyone have any ideas. Please help.

Comment: Does anyone now this?

Comment: I've tried some more ideas without success. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away from the coroutine by using a [State](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) design pattern.

```
public int SunRise = 8;
public int SunSet = 15;
public Quaternion RiseRotation;
public Quaternion SetRotation;
public int StartHour = 8; 

float time; // our time on a 24 hr system
bool wasSun; // what was our previous state?

void Start()
{
    GoToHour(StartHour);
    ToggleState(IsSun());   
}

void Update()
{
    bool isSun = IsSun();

    if (isSun != wasSun)
        ToggleState(isSun);

    time = (time + Time.deltaTime) % 24; // wrap at 24 hrs back to 0

    if (isSun) 
        UpdateSun();
    else
        UpdateMoon();
}

bool IsSun()
{
    return time >= SunRise && time < SunSet
}

void UpdateSun()
{
    float t = (time - SunRise) / (SunSet - SunRise);
    UpdateRotation(_lSunLight.transform, RiseRotation, SetRotation, t);
}

void UpdateMoon()
{
    float t;

    if (time >= SunRise)
        t = time - SunRise;
    else
        t = time + (24 - SunSet);

    t = t / ((24 - SunSet) + SunRise));
    UpdateRotation(_lMoonLight.transform, RiseRotation, SetRotation, t);
}

void GoToHour(int hour)
{
     t = hour / 24;
}

void ToggleState(bool isSun)
{
    if (isSun)
    {
        // Custom logic here, turn on sun, turn off moon?
    }
    else
    {
        // Custom logic here, turn on moon, turn off sun?
    }

    wasSun = isSun;
}

static void SetRotation(Transform target, Quaternion start, Quaternion end, float t)
{
    target.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(start, end, t);
}
```

Completely untested code, but this is a base idea for how you can use a class to update either the sun or the moon. This is a binary implementation, so either the sun is showing, or the moon is. If you want to have overlap, you can of course customize it do that easily. You will want different hours for the moon rise and moon set, and then not if/else the moon and sun update.

The code is also pretty basic and makes a lot of assumptions (sunrise never overlaps the 24 hour mark.) All of these can be cleaned up. You can also create variables to store calculations that are done each frame (regarding the duration of the sunrise/set) at your discretion. If you want to do that, just set it in the GoToHour method.

The SetRotation isn't super necessary, but it serves to keep the code clean. If you later decide you want to use a Quaternion.Slerp, you only have to change it in one place.

I exposed Quaternions in the inspector, you may rather using just a float for degrees, or a Euler Vecter3. If you do either, you can just do a conversion in the Start.

I hope this answered all your questions, if not, feel free to clarify on what isn't answered.